# What does the green star mean?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

This is my first post. I am new to SharePoint 2013. I am loving the platform. Can anyone tell me what the green star that is next to the Word Document labelled WritingLists means? Does it mean it's still Checked Out and no yet Checked In?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

**The green star shows up for new documents.**

When a new document is created/uploaded green star will be displayed. By default it showed for 2 days but you can change it as per your need.

Please read more here: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/new-tag-indicator-in-sharepoint.html

Also note in case of checkouts, you see the green arrow on the Word icon meaning the document is being editted.

Comment: just FYI, the same icon shows up in Office 365, but doesn't have a duration (it's there no matter how many times I "view" an item, weeks later)

Answer (score 2):

It means it's newly added content.  It will appear next to documents or plain old list items in regular lists.

Comment: it means recently added

Comment: SP 2010 and 2007 actually had a small "new" icon rather than the green star